# Gitlab issue tracking integration with Bugzilla

Tags: gitlab, bugzilla, issue-tracking

Been reading and googling around for a while and I've found enough information and run enough tests to verify that Gitlab is able to integrate with Redmine and JIRA for issue tracking, but what about bugzilla? The Gitlab external issue tracking document mentions bugzilla as one of the available systems it can communicate with, but so far I've been unable to find which configuration options to set in order to enable it. What am I missing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To clarify, here are the `gitlab.yml` changes that would work for Bugzilla:
`issues_tracker:
        bugzilla:
                title: "Bugzilla"
                project_url: "http://BUGZILLA_URL/describecomponents.cgi?product=:issues_tracker_id"
                issues_url: "http://BUGZILLA_URL/show_bug.cgi?id=:id"
                new_issue_url: "http://BUGZILLA_URL/enter_bug.cgi?product=:issues_tracker_id"`

Now I just need to figure out how to put this is gitlab.rb so I dont have to apply the changes after every `gitlab-ctl reconfigure`.

Comment: Nice feedback, more precise than my answer. +1

Comment: But how do you mention a Bugzilla bug id in GitLab then? For my configuration, it seems the only working syntax is ```ID-123``` but this always leads to GitLab trying to link to ```http://BUGZILLA...?id=ID-123```, which is not valid. I need some way to cut the ```ID-``` from the id.

Comment: I just figured it out myself: Mention Bugzilla bugs with ```#123``` and all is fine!

Answer (score 3):

GitLab now has Bugzilla as an external issue tracker option without having to modify your `gitlab.yml` file.

Go to your admin or project's Settings > Services > Bugzilla and fill in the `project_url`, `issue_url`, and `new_issue_url` from your instance of Bugzilla.  Note that the `issues_url` needs to have `:id` at the end of the URL. This ID is used by GitLab as a placeholder to replace with the issue number if mentioned in a comment or commit message.

See below for official docs:

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/integration/external-issue-tracker.md

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/project_services/bugzilla.md

Answer (score 1):

The only configuration mentioned in [`doc/integration/external-issue-tracker.md`](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/868755777f66f35eceeb55ca3caa160546eb7a00/doc/integration/external-issue-tracker.md) is the [External Issues Tracker section of the `gitlab.yml` configuration file](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/56a456b43dba7d772db45e2b73aa18b5eab53d37/config/gitlab.yml.example#L99-L100).

I suspect it depends how bugzilla expect its bugzilla url to be presented by GitLab

```
## If not nil, link 'Issues' on project page will be replaced with this
```

What follows should be bugzilla urls, using GitLab placeholder values like `:issues_tracker_id` or `:project_id`.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20225064/6309) mentions [GitZilla](http://www.theoldmonk.net/gitzilla/), but without much success.

Comment: I had two problems here:  
1. The Gitlab server I was using was downlevel, so whenever I made a change to the issues_tracker setting, a `gitlab-ctl restart` never really brought it back online.  
2. I've been looking at the `gitlab.yml` file and for some reason didn't process exactly what was in those comments. I read them as "this is how you configure jira or redmine" and was expecting something else for bugzilla.